# Class 'Entity\User' not found in proxy

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I had to move an existing site to another hosting (with the same software).
Now, when second user tries to do something with entities (programatically adding, editing or removing) the site fails with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Entity\User' not found in /home/.../www/includes/Objects/Proxies/__CG__EntityUser.php on line 9
```

Here is the config:

```
ini_set('include_path', ROOT_PATH.'/includes');
require_once(ROOT_PATH.'/includes/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php');
Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::registerAutoloadPEAR();

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup,
  Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
  Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
  Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\MysqlSessionInit;

$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
$config = new Configuration;
$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(ROOT_PATH.'/includes/Objects');
$driverImpl->getAllClassNames();
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
$config->setProxyDir(ROOT_PATH.'/includes/Objects/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('Objects\Proxies');
// developer mode
//$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
$em = EntityManager::create(array(
  'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
  'unix_socket' => '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
  'host' => DB_HOST,
  'user' => DB_USER,
  'password' => DB_PASS,
  'dbname' => DB_NAME
  ), $config);
$em->getEventManager()->addEventSubscriber(new MysqlSessionInit('utf8', 'utf8_unicode_ci'));
```

As I said I didn't changed nothing in code...

When the site in single-user state - everything is fine..

What can it be? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I have had to manually create the proxies with ./doctrine orm:generate-proxies (on the command line tool)

But make sure your file permissions are correct as sometimes they are trying to be auto-generated but the server won't allow it.